# Does this snippet of Qt project file cause the "LNK1112 module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86' fatal error"?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, qmake, nmake, qglviewer

My current development environment is Windows 8.1 + Visual Studio Pro 2013 (both are traditional Chinese versions) run on a VMware virtual machine. I followed the “How to install CGAL on Windows using Visual Studio 2010” instruction step by step as shown in http://www.cgal.org/windows_installation.html.

I have successfully built the latest Qt 4.8.6 that CGAL currently supports from source using MS VS2013 x64 complier. But when I tried to compile the latest libQGLVIewer-2.5.2 downloaded from libqglviewer.com, the NMAKE always failed with the LNK1112 fatal errors. I also tried to compile the libQGLViewer using Qt Creator, according to http://www.libqglviewer.com/installWindows.html, but the same error occurs.

I have contacted libqglviewer.com looking for help, and have made every effort to solve the issue per suggestion from libQGLView, but to no avail. Now I wonder if the culprit is in this section of QGLViewer.pro, which libQGLViewer said "That's very possible. These flags are old, and I have no way to test them. You can try to remove these and see if that fixes the problem. Sorry I cannot help more without VS on my machine. Keep me posted of your progress."

As I am still learning CGAL and new to Qt, I am not able to fix this problem on my own. Thank you for your kind help in advance.

```
# ---------------------
# --  W i n d o w s  --
# ---------------------
win32 {
  # Windows requires a debug lib version to link against debug applications
  CONFIG *= debug_and_release build_all

  # Needed by Intel C++, (icl.exe) so that WINGDIAPI is a defined symbol in gl.h.
  DEFINES *= WIN32

  staticlib {
        DEFINES *= QGLVIEWER_STATIC
  } else {
        DEFINES *= CREATE_QGLVIEWER_DLL
  }

  CONFIG *= embed_manifest_dll

  # Make sure to have C++ files, PentiumPro code, few warnings, add
  # support to RTTI and Exceptions, and generate debug info "program database".
  # Any feedback on these flags is welcome.
  !win32-g++ {
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -TP -GR -Zi
        DEFINES += NOMINMAX
        win32-msvc {
          QMAKE_CXXFLAGS *= -GX
        } else {
          QMAKE_CXXFLAGS *= -EHs
        }
  }
}
```